# Facebook Unity SDK issues when building for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am not being able to solve this build-time issue when building for Android.

Here's the error message:

```
AndroidManifest.xml:39: Tag <provider> attribute authorities has invalid character '$'.
```

I found, indeed, in the AndroidManifest.xml produced in the Temp/StagingArea folder the following lines:

```
 <!--
         The initialization ContentProvider will call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize automatically
         with the application context. This config is merged in with the host app's manifest,
         but there can only be one provider with the same authority activated at any given
         point; so if the end user has two or more different apps that use Facebook SDK, only the
         first one will be able to use the provider. To work around this problem, we use the
         following placeholder in the authority to identify each host application as if it was
         a completely different provider.
        -->

    <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.FacebookInitProvider" android:exported="false" android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider" />
```

It looks like the applicationId substitution is not working, but I correctly place it in the Facebook Settings, as stated in the docs.

Tried it with Facebook SDK 7.10, 7.11 and 7.12 on Unity 2017.2 and 2018.1 in an empty project with just the Facebook SDK plugin installed.

Anyone out there have any idea on what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this with your app id, $ returns package name not appID.

```
<provider android:authorities="FacebookInitProvider{APP ID HERE}" android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider" />
```